# Using `defines` with induction

Tags: isabelle

Consider following lemma which should be easily provable:

```
lemma
  fixes n m::nat
  defines "m ≡ n - 1"
  shows "m ≤ n"
proof(induction n)
  case 0
  then show ?case unfolding m_def 
      (* Why does «n» appear here? *)
next
  case (Suc n)
  then show ?case sorry
qed
```

However after unfolding `m`, the goal becomes `n - 1 ≤ 0` instead of `0 - 1 ≤ 0` rendering the goal unprovable since `n = 2` is a counterexample.

Is this a bug in Isabelle? How can I unfold the definition correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Javier pointed out, the `n` defined in the lemma head is different from the `n` created by `induction`. In other words, any facts from "outside" that reference `n` are not directly usable within the `proof (induction n)` environment.

However, Isabelle does offer a way to "inject" such facts, by piping them into `induction`:

```
lemma
  fixes n m::nat
  defines "m ≡ n - 1"
  shows "m ≤ n"
  using m_def (* this allows induction to use this fact *)
proof(induction n)
  case 0
  then show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc n)
  then show ?case by simp
qed
```

`using assms` will work just as well in this case.

Note that direcly referring to `m_def` is no longer necessary, since a version of it is included for each `case` (in `0.hyps` and `Suc.hyps`; use `print_cases` inside the proof for more information).

Answer (score 1):

I think a useful explanation could be the following: Recall the definition of `nat.induct`, namely

```
?P 0 ⟹ (⋀n. ?P n ⟹ ?P (Suc n)) ⟹ ?P ?n
```

and note that `?n` means that `n` is implicitly universally quantified, that is, the previous definition is equivalent to

```
⋀n. ?P 0 ⟹ (⋀n. ?P n ⟹ ?P (Suc n)) ⟹ ?P n
```

Now, when applying `nat.induct` to your example, clearly the first subgoal to prove is `?P 0`, i.e., `m ≤ 0`. However, in that context, `n` is still an arbitrary but fixed `nat`, in particular it does *not* hold that `n = 0`, and that is the reason why after unfolding the definition of `m` you get `n - 1 ≤ 0` as the new subgoal. With respect to your specific question, the problem is that you cannot prove your result by induction on `n` (but you can easily prove it using `unfolding m_def by simp`).